# on selecting an item in listbox disable a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

On selecting the firstitem in the list box my Up button should be disabled. similarly on selecting the Lastitem in the listbox Down button should be disabled. I can able to find which item is selected by using selected index

```
if (lstview.SelectedIndex >= 0)
  {
     var selectedItems = lstview.SelectedItems;
     foreach (ClassName selectedItem in selectedItems)
       {
         lstview.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
         break;
       }            
   }
```

but how to disable the up and down button based on selecting first item or last item in the list box

Comment: i mean btn.delete=true should happen if i click on first item or last item. how to achieve it?

Comment: just create a general function and call that function from your event - see my comment in beaners answer.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the selected index with 0, and the number of items in the list and set the Enabled property of your buttons based on the selected index.

```
private void lstView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    upButton.Enabled = lstView.SelectedIndex > 0;
    downButton.Enabled = lstView.SelectedIndex < lstView.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

Comment: i can make this to happen if i click on an event. but how to achevie it on clicking the first item in the list box

Comment: @user982129 your request is simple, put the code in a general function and call it from either code or from your button event.  Instead of having the code in your event just call the function inside of your event `btn_Click(sender s, event e) { myFunc(); } void myFunc() { //do code }`

Comment: ok can you please tell me when this btn_Click(sender s, event e) will be called.

Comment: for me if its called on selecting an item in the listbox it should be fine. but how to call this on selecting an item

Comment: @user982129 - the list has a SelectedIndexChanged event that is fired whenever the currently selected item changes, so if you click on the first item in your list and the first item was not previously selected it is fired. Adding your code to enable / disable you buttons inside this event will do what you want.

Comment: SelectedIndexChanged will be fired only when the items changed. but on just selecting an item it will not be triggered so i may have to compare the item with previously selected value...

Comment: @user982129 - I guess I don't understand then because I copied the code from the example into a test project with a listbox control and two buttons and it worked for me. If you mean this logic does not run when the form is loaded, just set the selected index in the form load event or some other convenient method.